# how can i send a video to telegram channel with python?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

how can I send a video to the telegram channel with python?
I have a bot and joined it on my channel!

```
def upload_video(title, desc):
    bot_token = 'my token'
    bot_chatID = '@PinkPanthersShow'
    files = {'document': (f'{title}.mp4', open(f'{title}.mp4', 'rb'), 'video')}
    data = {'chat_id': (f"{bot_chatID}", 'video')}
    send_document = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token

    r = requests.post(send_document,json=data,files=files)
    print(r.url)

    return r.json()
```

my code is this, but I can not send a video!
help me!

Comment: any help? .......

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. What exactly is not working? Please have a look at this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions. Please also remove the `python-telegram-bot` tag, which is reserved for the library of the same name and that you don't use in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def upload_video(file_path):
    bot_token = 'YOUR_TOKEN'
    bot_chatID = '@PinkPanthersShow'
    files = {'document': open(file_path,'rb')}
    data = {'chat_id': bot_chatID}
    method = 'sendDocument'
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/{method}'
    
    r = requests.post(url,data=data,files=files)
    print(r.url)
    return r.json()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).